# Stack trace in visual studio express

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, exception

I'm working on a WPF application with Visual Studio 2010 Express. I have a WinForm component running inside a `WindowsFormsHost`, that apparently contains an error. The only error message that is printed out in the console is

> Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException"
>   ist in mscorlib.dll aufgetreten.

(I'm using the German version). It does not print out a stack trace, nor does it tell me on which line the error occured. I can find the error by debugging through the whole code, anyhow sometimes I just want to see the stack trace to resolve the problem quicker.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Exceptions : Debug-> Exceptions

EDIT

Check this out, express related section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx

Regards