# Program execution ends suddenly, with no warnings or exceptions, ONLY when debugging!

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a very strange issue. My program runs absolutely perfectly if I run it without debugging (by pressing CTRL-F5), but if I try to run it with the debugger, it will crash back to the environment with absolutely no warning, error message, or exception. In fact, according to the output window, the program exited with error code 0, ie, normally!

I've tried running the program on two computers, on one it works absolutely fine and lets me debug it, but on the other it doesn't. That just makes it even odder! I'm using visual c# express 2010.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems like a problem with VS. Have you installed SP1 on top of VS2010?

Comment: Is there anything special about your program? For instance, you mention [tag:visual-studio-express], which developers building on [tag:xna] often use. Is it an XNA project? [tag:WinForms]? [tag:WebForms]? Anything in the [tag:EventViewer]? Does the program even start at all (i.e. run any code)?

Comment: I don't think there is an SP1 for the express edition...is there?

Yes, it uses an ActiveX control. This is definitely involved, as the "crash" happens as soon as I try to run a method of the control. However, the control itself must be good, as firstly it works fine when debugging isn't enabled, and secondly it works fine under all conditions on another computer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure have Exception enabled in VS.
2. Make sure to be subscribed to [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

And you will got to your crash reason.

**EDIT**

[How to enable exceptions in VS and VS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716426/stack-trace-in-visual-studio-express/6716435#6716435)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean exception enabled in VS? I've been through all the relevant check-boxes in VS settings and everything, and it all looks normal.

Also, I just tried using AppDomain.UnhandledException and nothing, still no crash reason.

Comment: Did you look on Windows Application Log ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know whether this is good or bad...but I no longer have access to that computer :P I was connecting through VNC, but that's down for now, so I won't know whether enabling exceptions fixes it or whether I can see an error report in Application Log for a while. Thanks for the help though.